# Manipular atributo do tipo Set no datatable primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Tenho uma tabela logradouro, bairro e logradouro_bairro.

```
logradouro (id, nome)
bairro (id, nome)
logradouro_bairro (id, id_logr, id_bairro)
```

Na entidade logradouro, tenho o mapeamento:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "logradouro", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Getter
@Setter
private Set logradouroBairro = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Na entidade bairro, tenho o mapeamento:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bairro", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Getter
@Setter
private Set logradouroBairro = new HashSet<>();
```

Na entidade logradouroBairro, tenho o mapeamento:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_bairro", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_logr_id_bairro"))
@Getter
@Setter
private Bairro bairro;
```

Bom, gostaria de saber qual seria a maneira mais indicada de adicionar/remover um bairro no datatable
ue tenho na view de logradouros, criar um List de bairros no logradouroBean, e manipular esse list com add/remove ou utilizar o próprio atributo
do logradouro: `private Set logradouroBairro = new LinkedHashSet<>();` para iterar no datatable?

Não sei qual a melhor forma de fazer, pensei em criar uma flag excluido/adicionado no List de bairros para identifcar
quais bairros devem ser incluidos/alterados no atributo logradouroBairro, mas acredito que não é uma boa prática.